# "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asyncIterator')", in Apollo Studio

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am getting the following response when doing  submitting a subscription in Apollo Studio and I am loosing my mind debugging! I can't seem to find the problem.

Usually everything would work when doing `server.installSubscriptionHandlers()` but now in Apollo version 3, according to the Documentation, things have to be done differently.
Read more here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/

My Packages:

```
"graphql-subscriptions": "^2.0.0",
"graphql-tools": "^4.0.8",
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.11.0",
"apollo-server-express": "^3.5.0",
"express": "^4.17.2",
```

Response in ApolloStudio:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asyncIterator')",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "newTodo"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I typed into ApolloStudio:

```
subscription {
  newTodo {
    description
    id
    title
  }
}
```

My relevant resolver code:

```js
const NEW_TODO = "NEW_TODO";

const resolvers: IResolvers = {
//...
Mutation: {
        addTodo: async (
            parent,
            args: null,
            { pubsub },
            info: any
        ): Promise<Todo> => {
            const newTodo: Todo = {
               id: v4(),
               title: "New Todo!",
               description: "New Todo, Wohoo" 
            }
            todos.push(newTodo);
            pubsub.publish(NEW_TODO, { newTodo });
            return todos[todos.length - 1];
        }
    },
    Subscription: {
        newTodo: {
            subscribe: (_, __, {pubsub}) => pubsub.asyncIterator(NEW_TODO),
        },
    }
}
```

My Typedef:

```
type Subscription {
    newTodo: Todo!
}
```

My Server:

```js
//...

const pubsub = new PubSub();

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({req, res}): any => ({req, res, pubsub}),
    plugins: [{
        serverWillStart: async () => {
            return {
                async drainServer() {
                    subscriptionServer.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }],
});

(async function() {
    await apolloServer.start();
    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: true }); 
})();

const httpServer = createServer(app);
const subscriptionServer = new SubscriptionServer({
    schema,
    execute, 
    subscribe,
    onConnect() {
        console.log("SubscriptionServer ready!");
    },
}, {
    server: httpServer,
    path: "/graphql"
});

//...
```

Comment: I don't use graphql, but `subscribe: (_, __, {pubsub}) => pubsub.asyncIterator(NEW_TODO),` is undoubtedly your problem, your callback isn't being passed the stuff you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jared Smith said, there was a Problem with `subscribe()` not receiving `pubsub`, so I kinda hacked something together by going to the server code and changing `const pubsub` to `export const pubsub` and I imported it into the resolvers. Seems like an unelegant solution but it does the job for now!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by setting the context on the websocket server using useServer, it seems that query and mutation have a different context than the subscription, here is my code

```
(async () => {
    const app = express();
    const httpServer = createServer(app);
    const pubsub = new PubSub();

    app.use(cors());

    const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers});

    const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
        server: httpServer,
        path: '/graphql',
    })

    const serverCleanup = useServer({ 
        schema, 
        context: (ctx, msg, args) => ({ pubsub }), // <-- SOLVES IT
        }, wsServer);

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        context: ({ req, res }: any) => ({req, res, pubsub}),
        plugins: [
            ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
            {
                async serverWillStart() {
                    return {
                        async drainServer(){
                            await serverCleanup.dispose();
                        },
                    };
                }
            },
        ],
    });
    
    await apolloServer.start();

    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });

    httpServer.listen({ port: 8000 }, () => {
        console.log(
            ` Query endpoint ready at http://localhost:8000${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`
        );
        console.log(
            ` Subscription endpoint ready at ws://localhost:8000${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`
        );
    });
})()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).